# ウィンドウ表示開始時に一瞬白く表示されるのを回避したい

Tags: .net, wpf

WPFで黒をメインカラーとしたウィンドウを作っているのですが、その表示開始時に一瞬白く表示され、それがフラッシュしてるように見えてしまいます。
この現象を回避したいのですが方法はありますでしょうか。

#### 再現例

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSimple.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Black" WindowState="Maximized">
  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

このように背景黒の最大化ウィンドウを表示すると、起動時に一瞬白く表示されます。
元の画面が黒いと目立ちやすく、二重に起動すると確認しやすいかと思います。
実際の使用環境ではWindowアプリモードを黒に設定したエクスプローラーからの起動で目立ちます。

#### 環境

- Windows 10 64bit (1903)
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

強引な手法ですが最小化状態で初期化してロード完了後に最大化することで描画が完了した状態で呼び出せます。

xaml

```
     Background="Black" WindowState="Minimized">
```

xaml.cs

```
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
     }

     private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
     }
```